# Send a variable's value through clicking a link

Tags: php

`row['filename']` below contains a filename fetched from database. I want to send the filename to `download_file.php` when the link is clicked.

```
<?php 

//other code
$filename=$row['filename'];
echo '<a href="download_file.php?name=$filename">' . "See file name" .'</a>';

?>
```

but in `download_file.php` I get only the word `$filename` instead of its value (the actual filename fetched from the db).  How can I pass the value of `$filename` to `download_file.php`? Where did I go wrong in my code?

Comment: Variables inside single quotes like `$foo` is not considered as a variable, it will just be "$foo", which is why if you want to use a variable you should enclose them inside double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like

```
echo '<a href="download_file.php?name="'.$filename.'>See file name</a>';
```

Or you can directly use `"` double quotes like :

```
echo "<a href='download_file.php?name=$filename'>See file name</a>";
```

Comment: the second one works! and for the first one I get nothing.... just empty! ........so anyway the second code works fine and I'm accepting it ---Thanks. @Gautam3164

Answer (score 2):

In single quotes you can't get the value of variables only with double quotes.

change to:

```
echo "<a href='download_file.php?name=$filename'>See file name</a>";
```

[about quotes in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Answer (score 2):

You used apostrophes as a string mark. If you use quotation marks you can use the anchor like that.

```
echo "<a href='download_file.php?name=$filename'>See file name</a>";
```